# Vanilla JS Stopwatch - Submitting time to database

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I've been using the Vanilla JS Stopwatch Script on a website, but I need to grab the final time and submit it to a database.

I've located the code to display and log in the console the time as HH:MM:SS but I can't find a way to grab the final time and add it to a form field.

I just wondered if anyone had done something similar to pull time into the value of the field so it can be submitted.

https://jsfiddle.net/zymLk973/

```
<div class="timer" onClick="startTimer()">00:00:00</div>
<div class="row" style="font-size:16pt; width:100%">
<div class="4u">
<div onClick="pauseTimer()" class=" hidebtn">
PAUSE TIMER</div>
</div>
<div class="4u">
<div onClick="startTimer()" class=" hidebtn">
START/RESUME TIMER</div>
</div>
<div class="4u">
<div onClick="resetTimer()" class=" hidebtn">
CLEAR TIMER
</div>
</div>
</div>

var startTimerButton = document.querySelector('.startTimer');
var pauseTimerButton = document.querySelector('.pauseTimer');
var timerDisplay = document.querySelector('.timer');
var startTime;
var updatedTime;
var difference;
var tInterval;
var savedTime;
var paused = 0;
var running = 0;

function startTimer(){
if(!running){
startTime = new Date().getTime();
tInterval = setInterval(getShowTime, 1);
paused = 0;
running = 1;
timerDisplay.style.background = "#fff";
timerDisplay.style.cursor = "auto";
timerDisplay.style.color = "black";
startTimerButton.classList.add('lighter');
pauseTimerButton.classList.remove('lighter');
startTimerButton.style.cursor = "auto";
pauseTimerButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
}

function pauseTimer(){
if (!difference){
// if timer never started, don't allow pause button to do anything
} else if (!paused) {
clearInterval(tInterval);
savedTime = difference;
paused = 1;
running = 0;
timerDisplay.style.background = "#fff";
timerDisplay.style.color = "#690000";
timerDisplay.style.cursor = "pointer";
startTimerButton.classList.remove('lighter');
pauseTimerButton.classList.add('lighter');
startTimerButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
pauseTimerButton.style.cursor = "auto";
} else {
startTimer();
}
}

function resetTimer(){
clearInterval(tInterval);
savedTime = 0;
difference = 0;
paused = 0;
running = 0;
timerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Start Timer';
timerDisplay.style.background = "#fff";
timerDisplay.style.color = "#fff";
timerDisplay.style.cursor = "pointer";
startTimerButton.classList.remove('lighter');
pauseTimerButton.classList.remove('lighter');
startTimerButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
pauseTimerButton.style.cursor = "auto";
}

function getShowTime(){
updatedTime = new Date().getTime();
if (savedTime){
difference = (updatedTime - startTime) + savedTime;
} else {
difference =  updatedTime - startTime;
}
// var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
//var milliseconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 100);

var formatted = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

console.log(formatted);


hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
//milliseconds = (milliseconds < 100) ? (milliseconds < 10) ? "00" + milliseconds : "0" +              milliseconds : milliseconds;
timerDisplay.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem actually? Getting the final time, or setting it in a form? And by the way, why a form? If you want to submit it to your backend, why not directly using fetch to send it?

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to get the final time to post in the value of a form field which submits to a php mysql database. It's one field inside part of a form which submits other bits like the date and id of the user which is already setup on the system I am working on. I just can't figure out a way to grab the time and allow it to be a value in the form field, or even echo it out in php and do it that way.